# Multiple signed URL's for same S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I wanted to know if it is possible to have multiple cloudfront signed URL's for 1 object at the same time. 
e.g. my application will autogenerate signedURL's for lets say s3/myfolder/myimage.jpg
now it is possible that multiple EC2's running in different parts of the world generate signedURL's for the same object at the same time. 
So will they all be able to live and serve simultaneously?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  You can generate as many URLs as you wish for the same object.

Comment: Is it possible for one multiple object same sign URL I mean sign the parent object and then use the sign url for those object ? M y requirement is I have main hls playlist file and child playlist inside that so I could sing the main playlist file then others won't get affected I just wanna know how to allow access to the child objects using same sign url